# How to turn off logging when release to store

Tags: flutter

How to turn off the logging in flutter when the application is signed and release to the store?

aka in android when we select if the build config debug

Comment: you can use logger to just have log in debug mode

Answer (score 1):

Just Commit out the logging command before releaseing